# Res not working after receiving JSON from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to make a simple code works, but i have a little problem that i can't understand.

So, i am trying to send to server (Express 4.16), a form in JSON, with POST method. My server receive it (i can see it with console log req.body), but none of res methods are working (it just pass through it, res.send, res.json, res.redirect... and witout any errors..).

There is my code :

app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'))
})

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
 console.log(req.body)
 res.send(`You did it ${req.body.name} !! `)
})

app.listen('8080')
```

main.js

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
 let form = document.getElementById("id-form")

 function sendData() {
  let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest()
  let data = {}
  
  for (const input of form.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
   data[input.name] = input.value
  }

  XHR.open('POST', '/')
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  let dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data)
  XHR.send(dataToSend)
  
  }

   form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault()

     sendData()
 })
})
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your `res` commands are working just fine, the problem is that your `XHR` does nothing with the response. Try something like `XHR.onload = function (res) { alert(res); };` (you are using AJAX, which runs in the background; the browser doesn't navigate to the reply like when you submit a form the regular way)

Comment: You might want to try using bodyparser instead of `express.json()`. see: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters

Comment: Hello, Thanks @ChrisG, I understood now, and it works good ! I am able to reach my JSON,to use it in my server and send it again to my client ! 
I wasn't understanding that my server can't process Ajax as if it was a simple HTML request ! 

It should be the good answer, but i can't mark is as an answer as it is a comment..

Comment: For the bodyparser, i was using it @StevenStark, but i saw on the net that Express 4.16 now bundle it, and is obselete to use bodyparser now.

Comment: @WalidM. good to know, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not processing the response from the server in `XHR.send(dataToSend)`, but you should be able to see the response in the network tab on the Chrome Devtools (or its equivalent in a different browser).

Comment: Yep i can see my console.log in my client and in my server (data is received), and i see that the xhr is good (status 200 and sent).